# Find a unit vector

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces, solution-verification

**Find a unit vector that is perpendicular to the line with parametric equations x = 2t - 1, y = -t -1, z = t + 2 and the vector u = i - j.**

My solution:

From the parametric equations: **v** = <2,-1,1>

So the **w** = v x u = \begin{bmatrix}i&j&k\\2&-1&1\\1&-1&0\end{bmatrix} = i + j -k

And the desired vector is **w** = **w**/**||w||** where **||w||** = √3

**Is my solution correct?**

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @Matt Is my solution correct?

Comment: Is vertical like perpendicular? If it is then the solution is correct because the cross product gives us a vector that is perpendicular to the directional vector $v$ of the line and the vector $u$, then just normalize the result and you have the unit vector.

Comment: @MathLasker Yes. Thank you for your feedback!